# Maven doesn't seem to be downloading the whole jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, guava

I am following this [tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted) to create tests using Selenium. I have added the `com.google.guava` dependency to my `pom` like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>r09</version>
</dependency>
```

However, maven seems to be downloading this jar incompletely. There seem to be classes missing. One such is the `com.google.common.base.Optional`. On the [maven repo page](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/r09), towards the bottom under Source Control there is a [link](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse#git/guava/src/com/google/common/base) that shows code with the `Optional` class. But when I look under Maven Dependencies in eclipse, I see this:

(there is no class named `Optional`)

[image: No class named optional]

**Where are the rest of the classes?**

I have tried re-downloading the jar multiple times but it has had no effect.

Some more information:

I am adding the selenium server dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.41.0</version>
</dependency>
```

StackTrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Optional
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.loadCustomExtension(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:156)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.addWebDriverExtensionIfNeeded(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:148)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:80)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:191)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
at com.amsgeo.mspWebManager.web.ui.SeleniumTest.testingSelenium(SeleniumTest.java:17)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Optional
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 33 more
```

Comment: why r09? The latest is 17.0...

Comment: I guess I made the foolish assumption that the top listed item here was the most recent... http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava

Comment: A better source for finding the most recent version would be the Guava [project page](https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) or [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.google.guava%22%20AND%20a%3A%22guava%22), which lists releases chronologically starting with the most recent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Optional` was added in Guava 10.0. Also note that the most recent version of Guava is 17.0 and that 9.0 (r09) is over 3 years old at this point.

(Also, it appears that selenium 2.41.0 depends on Guava 15.0: see the `<dependencyManagement>` section of the pom [here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.seleniumhq.selenium%7Cselenium-parent%7C2.41.0%7Cpom).)

Answer (score 4):

You are using an old version of [google-guava package](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22com.google.guava%22%20AND%20a%3a%22guava%22), cause google guava is in the meantime at version 17. And the problem you are facing that you are looking against the current most-up-to-date code in version control.